# Copy folder contents into Access database

Tags: ms-access

I was wondering if anyone might know how to import the *contents* of a folder into a Access table.

I have a database that's used to make ID cards for students with a unique ID. When students get their photos taken to be printed on these cards, the files are saved as jpegs with the student ID numbers as the filename. (E.g., student 1234567's photo would be saved as 1234567.jpg.) These photos are all saved in the same folder.

I would like to be able to have Access (or a script) automatically generate a table for this folder with two columns: the filename and the image (as a BLOB). That way, I would be able to add a student's photo to his or her data record with a simple SQL query.

My VBA skills are not great (I'm in the process of learning), so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an MS article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103257, however, with the recent version of Access (2010), you would be better to consider the attachment data type which will also allow you to display the photo on a form.